loading for layout and page nextjs 14
I have a user page, the structure looks like this: folder [id]:

layout.tsx

import UserLayout from '@/components/screens/user/layout/UserLayout'

interface ILayout {
    children: React.ReactNode
    params: {id: string}
}

export default async function Layout({ children, params: {id}}: ILayout) {
    const user = await getUser(id)

    return <UserLayout user={user}>{children}</UserLayout>
}


(main)/page.tsx

export default async function Page({ params: { id } }: IPage) {
    const user = await getUser(id)

    return <User />
}


(main)/loading.tsx

import UserLoader from '@/components/screens/user/loader/UserLoader'

export default function Loading() {
    return <UserLoader />
}


courses/page.tsx

export default async function Page({ params: { id } }: IPage) {
    const courses = await getCoursesByUserId(id)

    return <UserCourses courses={courses} />
}


courses/loading.tsx

import UserCoursesLoader from '@/components/screens/user-courses/loader/UserCoursesLoader'

export default function Loading() {
    return <UserCoursesLoader />
}

the layout itself sends a request to obtain information about the user, this request is also made in (main)/page.tsx, and in courses/page.tsx there is already a request to obtain user courses, I use skeleton in loading.tsx and for Each page in [id] has its own, but I also need Skeleton for the layout because it also sends a request. how to implement this

Can't your wrap your layout using react Suspense ? Like for example: return <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading feed...</p>}><UserLayout>{children}</UserLayout></Suspense>

thus the skeleton itself for the layout does not appear, nextjs waits for the layout itself to load, and then the layout itself appears with the page loading

I was able to display a skeleton for the layout, but the skeleton page is not shown

loading.tsx only wrapped page.tsx and other children. Have you tried fetching user in UserLayout? and wrapped that with Suspense.

yes, I tried that, the skeleton layout itself is displayed, but the skeleton page is not
